# Using grid to create and save a small png file

Tags: r, r-grid

I am using R to create a number of small graphics that will be saved as PNG files, typically at 50x50 pixels, which for eventual use in a much larger image as icons or markers. As the content changes frequently, it is desirable that these be created programmatically rather than manually.

Because the content is also simple - a few characters of text and some numbers -  the `grid` functions seemed like a straightforward way to tackle this. I don't know `grid` at all well as I typically use higher-level libraries such as `ggplot2`. The MRE below lays out what I have already achieved.

This generates output, but I am having problems linking the sizes and scales of `viewport` and the various `grobs` to the ultimate PNG file. What I get is the below, which is fine at first glance, but is a 480x480 pixel image, most of which is unused, with the central graphic taking up only a third of the width and height.

That seems logical given the viewport sizing (`=.3`), but if I enlarge the viewport, then presumably I have to enlarge the text and so on. (I know how to change the `png()` parameters to adjust the density, number of pixels and so on, but at this point the image itself is the issue.)

The question boils down to how to best generate a decent-quality 50x50 pixel PNG or SVG file from a graphic such as this, created in R, either using `grid` or some other approach.

[image: PNG file output]

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
png(bg = "transparent")
pushViewport(viewport(width=.3, height=.3, clip="off"))
grid.rect(gp=gpar(lty=0, fill="#008000"))
grid.text("15.5", x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.75, "npc"),
          just = "center", hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, rot = 0,
          check.overlap = FALSE, default.units = "npc",
          name = NULL, gp = gpar(fontsize=48), draw = TRUE, vp = NULL)

grid.text("13h 20m", x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.25, "npc"),
          just = "center", hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, rot = 0,
          check.overlap = FALSE, default.units = "npc",
          name = NULL, gp = gpar(fontsize=32), draw = TRUE, vp = NULL)

lg <- linesGrob(x = unit(c(0, 1), "npc"),
                y = unit(c(0.5, 0.5), "npc"),
                gp = gpar(lwd=2))
grid.draw(lg)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Ultimately you need to constrain the size with `png('test.png', width = 50, height = 50, bg = "transparent")`, but you'll have to adjust the sizes in what you're plotting to fit in that device.

Comment: Thank you. It's conceptualising the size adjustments - as opposed to using trial and error - that is causing me the problems. Can I not create it at a larger size and resize it when saving, that sort of thing.

Comment: You can't easily resize because you open the device before drawing. `npc` units are taking care of most of the relative sizing for you, but you need to drop the `width` and `height` so from `viewport` so it uses the default `npc` values (which are what you want), and lower the `fontsize`s, which can't be `npc` (`16` and `12` looks about right). To generalize, you might consider at least starting with SVGs instead of PNGs, as the former are designed to scale well.

Answer (score 1):

`magic` library may be helpful for that. I used your starting codes to create an empty png file.

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
png(bg = "transparent")
pushViewport(viewport(width=.3, height=.3, clip="off"))
dev.off()
```

Then I read that png file to put inside the `magic` codes as below. Actually, there may exist a way to put the png file directly into the `magic` in your R session without making temporary write - read works. However ,if you have got a lot of files to create and save as png, it is not so important to read an empty png file once. Since it can be used as for all new outputs.

```
library(magick)

img <- image_read("./desktop/Rplot001.png")

output <- img %>% image_background("#008000") %>% image_resize("50x50") %>% 
          image_annotate("15.5", size = 17, gravity = "north", location = "+1+4",color = "black", boxcolor = NULL) %>% 
          image_annotate("13h 20m", size = 11, gravity = "south", location = "+0+7",color = "black", boxcolor = NULL)

image_write(output, path = "./desktop/output.png", format = "png")
```

It gives a 50x50 png file,

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I'm actually using Imagemagick and the magick library for another part of the workflow, but I would like to improve the original image created in R.